# Run expect command inside while loop in shell script

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, expect, scp

I have list of filenames in a text file,need to transfer each file into server using scp command.I am reading filenames from **Read.sh** and passing each file name to **transfer.sh** script but scp is not executing command in this transfer script.If I run **transfer.sh** alone with passing args its working fine.

**List.txt**

```
/home/kittu/file1.txt
/home/kittu/file2.txt
/home/kittu/file3.txt
```

**Read.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
while read p; do
  echo $p
    ./transfer.sh "$p"
done <List.txt
```

**transfer.sh**

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

# get filename from command-line
set f [lindex $argv 0]

spawn scp "$f" user@192.168.4.151:/home/user/Desktop/ 
expect "password"
send "123\r"
interact
```

I just run Read.sh as

```
>./Read.sh
```

**Output:**

```
/home/user/Desktop/file1.txt
spawn scp /home/mbox140/Desktop/test.sh mbox140@192.168.4.151:/home/mbox140/Desktop/videos/
user@192.168.4.151's password:
```

Its not executing next statement.Please suggest me any solution.

Comment: have you tried running the transfer.sh standalone, is it working? and in the transfer.sh the interact command should throw error since you are trying to communicate to the closed process ( in this case scp )

Comment: @Ram yes,transfer working as standalone.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the below script , The changes are that the Transfer.sh is wrapped into bash.sh.
and the reason it waits in the password may be because you are expecting a wrong pattern , try "Password" instead of "password" and after send command, expect for the terminal pattern so that the scp finishes

```
#!/bin/bash
while read p; do
echo $p
{
    /usr/bin/expect << EOF
    spawn scp $p user@192.168.4.151:/home/user/Desktop/
    expect "Password"
    send "123\r"
    expect "*#*"
EOF
}
done <List.txt
```

Comment: thanks for ur comment,I have tried above code here I am getting sytax error and warning: here-document at line 4 delimited by end-of-file (wanted `EOF')
syntax error: unexpected end of file

Comment: The problem is due to copy paste error you have to remove the extra spaces in the starting of the each line, try this command "sed -i 's/^ *//g' filename" over the script and rerun the script , sorry for the bad formatting

Comment: Hey,I just removed echo $p,its working.Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Is it possible to remove a line that matches $p inside while loop.Because I want to remove filename from List.txt once file got transfered to server.???

Comment: Do you refer to the line "spawn scp $p user@192.168.4.151:/home/user/Desktop/"?