# expect script variable assignment

Tags: unix, expect

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
set NUM [exec some command to ssh to a remote machine and return a number]
puts $NUM
while { $NUM != "0" } {
        set NUM [exec some command to ssh to a remote machine and return a number]
        sleep 5
}
```

The above is my code. It runs in an expect script. I want to assign the variable NUM to some command that ssh to a remote machine and return a number (this command will return a number when I type in the terminal).
And I got the error:

```
100
while executing
"exec some command to ssh to a remote machine and return a number "qstat | wc -l""
invoked from within
"set JOBS [exec some command to ssh to a remote machine and return a number "qstat | wc -l"]"
```

The thing is that I have got the number but I failed to assign that number to the variable NUM

Can anyone help me to debug this piece? Thanks

Comment: need to see the actual error message.

Comment: that is the actual msg, all I did is replace the command

Comment: @TheZoo : Update the post with the command you have used in `exec`.

Comment: just keep voting down this question. I want to tell you that the command in there would not matter unless its a primitive command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yon cannot do it because its an expect script, the best way to do it is to wrap the expect script in a bash script. see [Run expect command inside while loop in shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25758983/run-expect-command-inside-while-loop-in-shell-script)