# expect not taking ssh arguments while/for loop

Tags: bash, expect

I'm trying to include 'for' or 'while' loop to input the list of IP's

Even I tried with below solution, 
[Run expect command inside while loop in shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25758983/run-expect-command-inside-while-loop-in-shell-script)

```
#!/bin/bash
 while read p; do
 {
  /usr/bin/expect<<EOF
 set timeout 3
 spawn ssh -q -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no  "root@192.168.102.$p" cat 
 /sys/class/net/enp0s3/address
 expect "Password:"
 send "xxxx\r";
 interact
  EOF
   }
  done<IP
```

Below is the output, here you can see  on every iteration, command excecution is not happening, only printing/echoing in terminal

```
spawn ssh -q -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@192.168.102.105 
   cat /sys/class/net/enp0s3/address
   root@192.168.102.105's password: spawn ssh -q -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no 
   root@192.168.102.106 cat /sys/class/net/enp0s3/address
     root@192.168.102.106's password: spawn ssh -q -o 
    StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@192.168.102.107 cat /sys/class/net/enp0s3/address
```

May I know why the ssh arguments weren't taken in effect. I tried with single/double quotes no luck .

Comment: As an aside, https://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor

Comment: take a look at [*sexpect*](https://github.com/clarkwang/sexpect) with which you can write "Expect" scripts with shell code only.

Comment: I hope sexpect similiar to autoexpect. if the ssh arguments which needs to be taken care, if that works my requiremnet with be fix. I suspect there could be some missing..

Comment: it got worked, replaced "interact" with "expect eof" . thanks all for the support